# I want to add cover art to all the MKVs in a folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, matroska

I'm trying to batch add cover art to all my MKV files in Windows using Batch scripting but I can't. My file structure is like this:

```
Video1.mkv
Video1.jpg
```

Both video and image have the same filename, the only difference is the extension.

I've tried the following command:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.mkv) DO (
mkvpropedit.exe "%%~nf.mkv" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type 
"image/jpeg" --add-attachment "%%~nf.jpg"
)
```

It's weird how this command works for other apps and it's not working for MKVPropedit.

The result is:

```
Error: The file '%%~nf.jpg' could not be opened for reading: open file error.
```

My jpg files are not corrupt so I don't really know what that error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different variable letter in your FOR command. The letter f is one of the [pathname format letters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (the complete list is `a, d, f, n, p, s, t, x`). For example, use G as shown here:

```
FOR %%G IN (*.mkv) DO (mkvpropedit.exe "%%~nG.mkv" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg" --add-attachment "%%~nG.jpg")
```

[According to SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) G is a good choice because it provides the longest run of letters that don't conflict with any of the pathname format letters:

> %%G is a good choice because it does not conflict with any of the pathname format letters (a, d, f, n, p, s, t, x) and provides the longest run of non-conflicting letters for use as implicit parameters.
>   G > H > I > J > K > L > M

**Further,** if you're running this directly from the command prompt, you need to use single % characters, not double, as shown here:

```
FOR %G IN (*.mkv) DO (mkvpropedit.exe "%~nG.mkv" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg" --add-attachment "%~nG.jpg")
```

This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510117/2227908) provides more information on using FOR in and outside of batch scripts.

Comment: Your command didn't work. I got the result: %%G unexpected at this time.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: So there are differences? I didn't know. So if I want to use it in a .bat file, which is my intention, I should use it with %%G? If I want to use it directly from the command prompt, I should use %G? Very interesting.

Comment: See the link I provided for info about why you need to use two % only in a batch file. The coffee if the letter G is simply to avoid other letters that have other uses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. Really nice. I was trying this for day and I didn't know about. I found about it right here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: You're welcome. I expanded my answer a bit to provide more detail. Please tick the green check mark next to my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: The for command will only use the modifier letters without the meta variable. But to better distinguish **myself** I also use upper case meta variables and lower case  modifiers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by meta variable?

Comment: Sorry. I've tried your command and it didn't work. It says Error: The file 'video2.jpg' could not be opened for reading: open file error. I'm using FOR %%G IN (*.mkv) DO (mkvpropedit.exe "%%~nG.mkv" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg" --add-attachment "%%~nG.jpg")
 inside a batch file.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with the FOR command. Troubleshoot by running the command without FOR. Such as `mkvpropedit.exe "filename.mkv" --attachment-name "cover" --attachment-mime-type "image/jpeg" --add-attachment "filename.jpg"`. Also, you're missing a double quote in the filename of your .mkv file.

Comment: I found out about what was the problem. Your command is ok.